# ReactJS - Unexpected token '.' error

Tags: reactjs

I am starting with my react project on VS2013 working together with ASP.NET MVC. I have configured webpack and configuration seemed working well until I tried to implement the following class.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    this.state = { visible: true }
    render() { 
       /** Method definition **/
    ...
}
```

I am getting an error Unexpected Token at '.' at 'this.state'. I have already check es2015 is set as babel preset. If I remove state and toggleVisibility assignments, webpack bundles OK.

Any idea what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

It's a class so the correct syntax should be

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    state = { visible: true }
    render() { 
       /** Method definition **/
    ...
}
```

Also, the recommended way of defining initial state should be

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { visible: true }
    }

    render() { 
       /** Method definition **/
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `this.state` in a constructor like

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
     visible: true 
  };
}
```

Hence, your code should be

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      visible: true 
    };
  }

  render() {}
}
```

From [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> The constructor is the right place to initialize state. If you don't
>   initialize state and you don't bind methods, you don't need to
>   implement a constructor for your React component.